# AttributeError: module 'docx' has no attribute 'Document' while trying to execute .py file

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

I am trying to use "python-docx" to create a ".docx" file dynamically. But, it keeps giving me this error when I execute the python code stored in ".py" file:

> AttributeError: module 'docx' has no attribute 'Document'

To ensure the proper installation of "python-docx", I uninstalled and reinstalled the same package many times by using the following commands:

```
pip uninstall python-docx
pip install python-docx
```

I got the proper results too:

```
Requirement already satisfied: python-docx in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (0.8.10)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml>=2.3.2 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from python-docx) (4.3.1)
```

But, when I tried to run the .py file, I got the same errors again:

**docx.py**

```
    import docx
    doc = docx.Document()  
    doc.add_heading("The Heading",0)
    doc.save("test-doc.docx")
```

**Output**

> File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\python\learning\docx.py", line 1, in 
>     import docx
>    File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\python\learning\docx.py", line 2, in 
>     document = docx.Document()
>   AttributeError: module 'docx' has no attribute 'Document'

And the most strange thing is that the same commands in program file work perfectly fine when executed on by one in the terminal:

```
>>> from docx import Document
>>> doc = Document
>>> doc = Document()
>>> doc.add_heading("Creating adocument",0)
<docx.text.paragraph.Paragraph object at 0x0000015DFAD4A668>
>>> doc.save("C:/Users/user/Desktop/test-doc.docx")
>>> exit()
```

I am just completely clueless about the reason behind this. 
I need help.

Comment: try renaming your module to something other than docx.py

Comment: @jdigital I just tried to do so and found that there is no **docx.py** file in the **Lib** Folder. But, there is this one folder: **python_docx-0.8.10-py3.6.egg** that contains a **docx** folder and all the contents of the module.

Comment: your post says that the name of *your* module is docx.py.  change it to something else.

Comment: @jdigital 
Sorry for misinterpreting your suggestion. My code just worked after renaming it. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 3x don't do pip install docx instead go for

```
pip install python-docx
```

steps will be still same.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install python-docx==0.8.11
```

works as of Nov 2022